# Personnal implementation of Java events in Slick2D

Tags: java, events, delegates, function-pointers, slick2d

I'm making my own windowing system in Java with Slick2D right now and I want to add buttons to my windows! The thing is that I have no knowledge on events or such things... Everywhere I look it's events for JFrames but I want to make them myself. here's how I use my windows...

```
Window win = new Window("Window title", 0, 0, 300, 100);
```

An then this is where I'm at now, in my class inheriting from the Window class :

```
@Override
public void initializeComponents() {

    Button button1 = new Button("Button caption", 0, 0, 50, 20);
    button1.setBackColor(Color.lightGray); // just an example of a set I'd use
    button1.setOnClickEvent(button1_OnClick); // this is where I can't get it to work!
    this.addComponent(button1);

}

public void button1_OnClick() {
    System.out.println("button1 was pressed");
}
```

I used to do C# and I did something similar with delegates and it worked, but now Java doesn't have any delegates as I read (I might be wrong). I basicly want to know if there'S a good way to implement this so I could use it this way.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can't pass *just* a method. You'll have to create a wrapper "callback" class with the method in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a method as a parameter. You'll have to create a wrapper class that holds the method.

Something like:

```
public interface Callback {
    public void onMouseClick();
}

...

public class Button {
    ...
    public void setOnClickEvent(Callback c) {
        this.onClickEvent = c;
    }

    public void update() {
        if (clickDetected)
            onClickEvent.onMouseClick();
    }
}

...

button1.setOnClickEvent(new Callback() {
    public void onMouseClick() {
        button1_OnClick();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to look into the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) for this.

The basic idea is that you'll add `this` to the button as an Observer (aka: listener), and when the button does something interesting, it will let its observers know and they can act, or not, accordingly.